# How to include my Ajax calls in one function instead of calling different ones every time?

Tags: plugins, jquery, ajax

I'm doing something like this to refresh a widget:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); // Write our JS below here


function my_action_javascript() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'refresh_function_one',
    };

            setInterval(function() {
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (result) {


                $("#Firstdiv").html(result);

    });

            },5000);

});
</script> <?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_refresh_function_one', 'function_one');
```

But I have several calls like this, for example the second would be the same thing but with different values
For example:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript2' ); // Write our JS below here


function my_action_javascript2() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'refresh_function_two',
    };

            setInterval(function() {
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (result) {


                $("#Seconddiv").html(result);

    });

            },5000);

});
</script> <?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_refresh_function_two', 'function_two');
```

My code works perfectly fine, I would just like it to "look" better, not use as much code. I've tried using some sort of loop without much luck. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your code to look good you should properly format it first. Aside from that you are able to combine your AJAX (or to be exact your jQuery/javascript) into one block. Actually you should put it in a separate javascript file, but you can read all about that on the [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) on the Codex page (from where you got your code anyway) or in the [WP the right way book](http://www.wptherightway.org/en/javascript/README.html).

```
add_action(
    'admin_footer',
    'my_action_javascript'
);
function my_action_javascript() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            var data_one = {
                    'action': 'refresh_function_one',
                },
                data_two = {
                    'action': 'refresh_function_two',
                };

            setInterval( function() {
                    $.post( ajaxurl, data_one, function( result ) {
                        $( "#Firstdiv" ).html( result );
                    } );
                    $.post( ajaxurl, data_two, function( result ) {
                        $( "#Seconddiv" ).html( result );
                    } );
                },
                5000
            );
        } );
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action(
    'wp_ajax_refresh_function_one',
    'function_one'
);
add_action(
    'wp_ajax_refresh_function_two',
    'function_two'
);
```

Comment: _"If you want your code to look good you should properly format it first."_ ... +1

Comment: Fair enough, that is what you get from being a wise guy.. @kaiser